# Example of Non-Linear but Continuous Functionals on Bochner Space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, bochner-spaces

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $E$ be a separable Banach space (not $0$-dimensional).  Then, what are some examples of non-linear functionals on the Bochner-space $L^1_{\mu}(X,E)$ of $E$-valued weakly-measurable functions satisfying $\int_{x \in X} \|f(x)\|_E d\mu(x)<\infty$?

In particular, when does the functional $f\mapsto \int_{x \in X} F(f(x))d\mu(x)$ work for some measurable function $F$?

Comment: Very cheap way: post-compose any nonzero linear functional with a nonlinear function $\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Is there a general representation in the Lp case similar to the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem though?  (So I can get a nice class of cheap examples)?